# How to give color for particular td with its cell and alternate cell within a table?

Tags: html

I have a table with n number of rows in a alternate color.
     Now want to search a particular column (td) within the table and change its alternative cell with different color.

Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 0):

Try to use java script to do that.
search the column by id / td number.. and change the color of that column.